# onChange method is not working on all the fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've defined the initial Value for the input fields in useState Hook, here is the **code:**

```
const [name, setName] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        storeName: ""
    })
```

And I'm accessing the Value in the Material UI input fields here

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth={true} variant="filled" >
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="component-filled">Email</InputLabel>
                        <FilledInput id="component-filled" onChange={handleChange} name="email" value={name.email} />
                        {error.emailError}
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth={true} variant="filled">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="component-filled">Password</InputLabel>
                        <FilledInput id="component-filled" onChange={handleChange} type="password" name="password" value={name.password} />
                        {error.passwordError}
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth={true} variant="filled">
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="component-filled">Confirm Password</InputLabel>
                        <FilledInput id="component-filled" onChange={handleChange} type="password" name="confirmpassword" value={name.confirmPassword} />
                        {error.confirmPasswordError}
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth={true} variant="filled" >
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="component-filled">Store Name</InputLabel>
                        <FilledInput id="component-filled" onChange={handleChange} name="storename" value={name.storeName} />
                        {error.usernameError}
                    </FormControl>
```

The problem I'm getting is which I typed in other three fields "`Email`", "`Password`" and "`storename`" onChange is working fine but It's not accepting any value for "`Confirmpassword`", means I am unable to type in confirm password field.

Here is my `HandleChange` method:

```
const handleChange = e => {
        e.persist()
        setName(name => (
            {
                ...name,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        ))
}
```

I'm not sure, what I'm missing so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have spelling error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input name is `confirmpassword` but your name for it in state is `confirmPassword`. Change one to match the other and it should work.

```js
<FilledInput 
  id="component-filled" 
  onChange={handleChange} 
  type="password" 
  name="confirmPassword" 
  value={name.confirmPassword} 
/>
```